# SQLAlchemy throwing KeyError when using Association Objects with back_populates – example from documentation doesn't work

Tags: python, exception, sqlalchemy, keyerror

SQLAlchemy nicely documents [how to use Association Objects with `back_populates`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object).

However, when copy-and-pasting the example from that documentation, adding children to a parent throws a `KeyError` as following code shows. The model classes are copied 100% from the documentation:

```python
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData

Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData())

class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(50))
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parents")
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Association", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parents = relationship("Association", back_populates="child")

parent = Parent(children=[Child()])
```

Running that code with SQLAlchemy version 1.2.11 throws this exception:

```
lars$ venv/bin/python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    parent = Parent(children=[Child()])
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 417, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 249, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 414, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 737, in _declarative_constructor
    setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 229, in __set__
    instance_dict(instance), value, None)
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1077, in set
    initiator=evt)
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 762, in bulk_replace
    appender(member, _sa_initiator=initiator)
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1044, in append
    item = __set(self, item, _sa_initiator)
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1016, in __set
    item = executor.fire_append_event(item, _sa_initiator)
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 680, in fire_append_event
    item, initiator)
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 943, in fire_append_event
    state, value, initiator or self._append_token)
  File "/Users/lars/coding/sqlalchemy_association_object_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1210, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event
    child_impl = child_state.manager[key].impl
KeyError: 'parent'
```

I've filed this as a [bug in SQLAlchemy's issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/4329/keyerror-when-using-association-objects). Maybe somebody can point me to a working solution or workaround in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 5):

**tldr;** We have to use Association Proxy extensions *and* create a custom constructor for the association object which takes the child object as the first (!) parameter. See solution based on the example from the question below.

SQLAlchemy's documentation actually states in the next paragraph that we aren't done yet if we want to directly add `Child` models to `Parent` models while skipping the intermediary `Association` models:

> Working with the association pattern in its direct form requires that
>   child objects are associated with an association instance before being
>   appended to the parent; similarly, access from parent to child goes
>   through the association object.

```python
# create parent, append a child via association
p = Parent()
a = Association(extra_data="some data")
a.child = Child()
p.children.append(a)
```

To write convient code such as requested in the question, i.e. `p.children = [Child()]`, we have to make use of the [Association Proxy extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html).

Here is the solution using an Association Proxy extension which allows to add children to a parent "directly" without explicitly creating an association between both of them:

```python
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData

Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData())

class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(50))
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parents")
    parent = relationship("Parent", backref=backref("parent_children"))

    def __init__(self, child=None, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.child = child

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = association_proxy("parent_children", "child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parents = relationship("Association", back_populates="child")

p = Parent(children=[Child()])
```

Unfortunately I only figured out how to use `backref` instead of `back_populates` which isn't the "modern" approach.

Pay special attention to create a custom `__init__` method which takes the child as the *first* argument.

Comment: The custom `__init__` is unnecessary, if using the `creator=` argument of `association_proxy`.

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä, I will try that out and update my answer

Comment: To clarify @IljaEverilä 's comment, the `children = association_proxy` line needs to look something like: `children = association_proxy("parent_children", "child", creator=lambda child: Association(child=child)`. I was able to get this to work will using `back_populates` on both of my association table relationships (meaning no need to use `back_ref` as in the answer). Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

So to make a long story short.

You need to append an association object containing your child object onto your parent. Otherwise, you need to follow Lars' suggestion about a proxy association.

I recommend the former since it's the ORM-based way:

```
p = Parent()
p.children.append(Association(child = Child()))
session.add(p)
session.commit()
```

Note that if you have any non-nullable fields, they're easy to add on object creation for a quick test commit.